# Creating a https apigee api-proxy

Tags: security, https, apigee

We are evaluating Apigee to secure our APIs. The default api-proxy is http, and I dont see a way to make it secure. What we are trying to avoid is someone sniffing the network and getting a handle of the apikey and abusing access to our APIs.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Sharadha

Answer (score 1):

There are two hosts configured for every new organization. default (http) and secure (https).  Both can be used.  If you want to disable http access from your API proxy, you can remove the *Default* **VirtualHost** from the **HTTPProxyConnection** section your API Proxy endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, in the file /proxies/default.xml, change the following:

```
<HTTPProxyConnection>
    <!-- API façade URL -->
    <BasePath>/myAPI</BasePath>
    <VirtualHost>default</VirtualHost>
</HTTPProxyConnection>
```

to

```
<HTTPProxyConnection>
    <!-- API façade URL -->
    <BasePath>/myAPI</BasePath>
    <VirtualHost>secure</VirtualHost>
</HTTPProxyConnection>
```